# Running Fabcar example returns error: failed to endorse chaincode install

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am on Ubuntu 19.10, installed all the pre-requisites and have downloaded the fabric-samples git repository.

I am following the tutorial on this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/write_first_app.html)

I ran the first-network example and it worked fine. Now, when I am trying to run the fabcar example by running the command `./startFabric.sh javascript`, I am getting the following error:

```
...
2020-02-02 23:51:14.534 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 02c Sign: digest: 8A36B905991D6B72A6F487E93C79D468A35F402D6EB4F51E3323152A03A5B64E 
2020-02-02 23:53:04.531 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 02d Client received GoAway with http2.ErrCodeEnhanceYourCalm.
2020-02-02 23:53:04.531 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 02e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003e1620, CONNECTING
2020-02-02 23:53:04.531 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 02f transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
Error: failed to endorse chaincode install: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

It looks like the error is generated when it executed:

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer --tls=true --cafile=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --orderer=orderer.example.com:7050 lifecycle chaincode install fabcar.tar.gz
```

I assume I aam using the latest version of hyperledger-fabric v2.0.0, since I am in the master branch of the fabric-samples repository. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open ports in the firewall.

in ubuntu I fix it using :

```
$ sudo ufw allow 4422/tcp
```

repeat for each docker container port,

You can view ports via :

```
$ docker ps
```

Answer (score 1):

I had/have the same issue. What worked in my case was what I have described in my own question here - [Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 byfn.sh error installing chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61239286/10382340)

Basically, even though there is an error (for some reason I do not know), the chaincode installation process is alive in the background and the chaincode does get installed.

I saw this behavior and put in a sleep statement for 10 minutes (600 s). I still do not know why this behavior is there (hence my question) but I have a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stopped the `first-network` at first by using `./byfn.sh down` before you jump into `fabcar` ?

Can I see some logs like `docker ps -a` and `docker logs peer0.org1.example.com`?

Also the HLF has recommended to use `test-network` as a replacement for `first-network` which is deprecated by now.

BTW, I would use the release branch other than master. Afterall the master branch is always under developing.